# Oracle - how select column and show the difference based on average?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, average

I have column item_name and item_cost. But when i want to show a difference using AVG(item_cost) always give me an error

> not a single-group group function

I just want to make a list of `item_name`, item_cost and show difference each item_cost with average of all item_cost using `avg(item-cost) - item_cost`.

This is my query syntax. What wrong with my syntax?

```
SELECT item_name,
    item_cost,
    AVG(item_cost) AS Avgcost,
    AVG(item_cost)-item_cost AS Difference
FROM item;
```

Comment: You can't mix "normal" column selects with group functions like `avg()`. You need to group.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `OVER ()` clause

```
SELECT item_name,
    item_cost,
    AVG(item_cost) OVER () AS Avgcost,
    AVG(item_cost) OVER () -item_cost AS Difference
FROM item;
```

Comment: what is OVER () mean? sorry i'm new on database

Comment: @sekti92 : `AVG(item_cost) OVER ()`   here implies average item_cost of all items fetched in select.

Comment: this syntax is working"
select concert_name, avg(concert_cost) as average_cost from concert group by concert_name;"

but when add new column like 
"avg(concert_cost) - concert_cost as difference "

give me an error. why is that?

Comment: Because CONCERT_COST isn't in the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: @sekti92 : If you  use group by, then the average you calculated won't be the average of all item_cost, which you were expecting. It is just equal to  item cost

Comment: @KaushikNayak How i can get the result of item_name, item_cost and the avg(item_cost) without using OVER()?

Comment: @sekti92 : Why are you so reluctant to adopt a syntax which was so far unfamiliar to you, although it gets your job done?

Comment: @Kaushik well, because the syntax you given to me to advance sir, and i tried to follow based on my sql book and tried to analyse it. Sorry if I make you upset. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here's another option, without analytic functions.

```
WITH avgcost AS (SELECT AVG (item_cost) avg_cost FROM item)
SELECT i.item_name,
       i.item_cost,
       a.avg_cost,
       a.avg_cost - i.item_cost diff_cost
  FROM item i, avgcost a;
```